# How to make crud entry email approval in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, verification

I have a simple crud application which has Users and Post CRUD Menu
I want like if any user create a post that post must be verified by that same user and then only that should be listed in the table .

I want to know if that is possible in laravel 
I am using Laravel 5.7

If Anyone can help me out with it or if anyone can share me reference links to it 
??????

Answer (score 0):

What you are tring to do is easily achieved by using a simple update() on the model. You will find that in the Laracast  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/approving-and-disapproving-an-application-in-laravel][1]

Comment: No I dont want admin approval I want the post to be approved by that user who created it through email